# Issue with keeping track of score in snake like game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am creating a simple snake like game in js/canvas of a cat catching food and for some reason I cannot get the score to work

http://jsfiddle.net/m0pk8s78/3/

```
 document.getElementById("gamescore").innerHTML = "Your score is:" +     score;
```

I am also wondering if anyone has any ideas on how I could change the food type everytime the user gets a score of 10, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either initialize the variable `score` in the global scope, or if you want to initialize it within the `init()` function, get rid of the `var` keyword.

**Option 1:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //Canvas stuff
  .
  .
  var score = 0;
```

**Option 2:**

```
function init() {
  .
  .
  score = 0;
```

Comment: Yup, removing `var key` for `score` will work for sure.

Answer (score 1):

you need to initialize score to a number at the top of your code before trying to increment it

`var score = 0;`